# How to disable text message notifications when sleeping?

Tags: notifications

Text message notifications like WhatsApp sometimes wake me up during nighttime. Turning off my phone isn't an option since I need the alarm, and turning off notification volume (or silent mode) just sets me up for trouble since I will forget to bring it back up, missing important texts.

Is there a way to disable text messages between 10 PM and 8 AM?

Comment: What phone?  In Android 5.0 and up there's a Do Not Disturb mode which you can set for a specific time frame/days of week/and select exceptions too.  It is under Settings - Sound & notification (on my N6), or Settings - Sounds and vibration (on my Galaxy S7 Edge).

Comment: @RMarkwald that could be an answer :)

Comment: Submitted as one.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android 5.0 and up there's a Do Not Disturb mode which you can set for a specific time frame/days of week/and select exceptions too. It is under Settings - Sound & notification (on my N6), or Settings - Sounds and vibration (on my Galaxy S7 Edge)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

It lets you modify notifcations and alarms based on a selection of conditions - in your case, you can set the notification volume based on current time.